# Material is not showing in eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine

When i wanna asign material to my mesh i'm not getting any result except this one: [image]

I have no idea what is wrong, also on the carpet i cannot get material to work. Do not know if is it a Blender 2.8 bug or i'm doing something wrong. I hope that somebody will know the answer. Thanks in forward for the help.

Comment: Yes, the top one is correct, botom one is basic material for the walls and the celing. Also preview of the material is not showing texture which is seen in UV part.

Comment: Yes, edit mode, select faces, assign. I'm already have a headache from several hours of trying to find what is wrong. :)

Comment: Which object are you trying to put a material on? Just the carpet?

Comment: Later i found out that was my mistake. I did'nt change mix into multiply on the shader node and some other minor (begginer) mistakes. Now is ok, with another problems. Now i cannot get reflection from the mirror which i put over the bed. Reflection is shown in viewport but when scene is rendered there is just transparent glass. I'm using reflection plane, already spend around 6 hours, changed probably every parameter and still not figured out.